# Windows: how to attach executable as a service from browser context?

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, psexec

i have a requirement to redirect laptop to a specific URL to download a stub(an exe) and later start the exe as a service on the endpoint. i went throw SC.exe and other commands however need inputs on what browser technology can be used to do the same?. seems like Java script or HTML5 does not seem to have have permission to run sc.exe command.

Comment: experts!! need your advice very badly....i am looking for a way to pul binary to laptop via browser...can browser plugin help here???

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, JavaScript and HTML do NOT have this ability, by design.

In old versions of Internet Explorer (Prior to Windows 7 SP1) you can do this with ActiveX, if it's enabled by the user, and if the user allows it to run on the page. (Most of the time, it is not enabled)

Open notepad.exe example:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var command = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"; 
shell.ShellExecute(command,"","","open","1");
```

However because this is VERY INSECURE, the feature was never adopted by other browsers, and was removed from IE as well. The only way to achieve what you want, is to have the user download an EXE or Java program that makes the required changes to the system, like an installer does.

Comment: thanks Austen, seems like this is the only option i.e to send installer to endpoint. as a administrator wanted to run some task in background to collect info from all windows endpoints however don't want to install one more app for it. if thr is a way to push some code TEMPORARILY (with require admin privilege) and then vanish is good enough for me

Comment: You could have the user download a portable executable which does not 'install' anything. However the file would still be in the users download's directory (or wherever it was downloaded to). I do not believe there is a way to 'self destruct' an executable, however I could be wrong.